# ¿Cómo crear el nombre de una variable de manera dinámica?

Tags: c#

Lo que me gustaría realizar es la generación automática del nombre de mi variable de tipo `DataTable`, quiero que su nombre siempre vaya en incremento haciendo un nombre único e identificable.

Código actual:

```
for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
{
     consulta[z]= "select * from v_Autorizaciones where Empresa='" + valores[z] + "'" + "|";
    DataTable tb_menu+z = new DataTable();
}
```

Como se puede apreciar, en el código me marca un error en `DataTable tb_menu+z = new DataTable();` ya que le estoy asignando un valor numérico al supuesto nombre que debería tener la variable de tipo `DataTable`. Me gustaría que el resultado fuera algo como `tb_menu0`, `tb_menu1`, `tb_menu2`, `tb_menu3`, etc.

Comment: C# es fuertemente tipado asi que no podés crear variables con nombres dinámicos. Algunos sugieren crear un arreglo o un diccionario. Investiga por ese lado.

Comment: No se puede, lo recomendable es crear una lista o un arreglo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una opción es, que en lugar de crear variables dinámicas mejor declares una lista de `DataTable` de la siguiente forma:

```
List<DataTable> listaDataTable = new List<DataTable>();
for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
{
    //Aquí van las secciones de tu código deseado
    DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();
    listaDataTable.Add(objDataTable); //<-- Con .Add agregamos el objeto DataTable a la lista
}
```

Ahora, para hacer uso de esos `DataTable` solo tienes que iterar tu lista:

```
foreach(DataTable item in listaDataTable)
{
    //Aquí van las secciones de código que debes poner para manejar cada uno de esos DataTable
}
```

## Actualización

Otra forma de resolverlo es creando un diccionario con la definición `<int, DataTable>` donde el valor entero es el consecutivo y se irían agregando los `DataTable`'s según las iteraciones realizadas:

```
Dictionary<int, DataTable> dictDataTables = new Dictionary<int, DataTable>();
for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
{
    //Aquí van las secciones de tu código deseado
    DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();
    dictDataTables.Add(z, objDataTable);
}
```

Ahora, para poder acceder a los elementos del diccionario, por ejemplo, deseamos acceder al `DataTable` que se agregó con `Id = 2`:

```
DataTable dataTableObtenido = dictDataTables.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == 2).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso no se puede hacer. Te aconsejo que mejor crees un arreglo de datatables y lo accedas así:

```
tb_menu[z] = new DataTable();
```